# android accessibility service is preferable or not for getting notifications?

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am bit confusion regarding Android accessibility services.

Android accessibility service is preferable or not for getting notifications?

Comment: it looks a bit confusing ques..for getting notification you dont even need to use accessibility service

Comment: For getting Notifications you can use Notification.Builder

Answer (score 1):

No, Accessibility Services are used to help visually impaired people.
To manage notifications refer the link below

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html